# Parse multi-nested conditional C-preprocessor statements in Perl

Tags: c, perl, parsing, conditional-statements, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to come up with a way to easily parse some C-header files. I have three header files, File_A1, File_A2 and File_B. 
File_A*'s contains solely `#defines`. The `#defines` themselves may either map to a Boolean value, numerical data, or a conditional statement like `(E && F)`, where `E` and `F` are defined earlier in the file. For example:

FILE_A1

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define USERWARE                                TRUE
#define SECTION_SIZE                            2
#define ENGR2_LOAD_ADDRESS                      0x6FF020
#define INTEGER_ONLY_SUPPORT                    FALSE
#define PRESSURE_SENSOR_MIN_KPA_DELTA           -50
#define DUMMY_ENGR2_LOAD_ADDRESS                0x92059020
#define FAST_FLUSH_SUPPORT                      USERWARE
```

FILE_A2 is very similar.

File_B is a bit more complicated in terms of the definitions. It contains nested #define statements, many of which are surrounded by `#if...#elif...#endif`, so something like:

FILE_B

```
#include "File_A1.h"
#include "File_A2.h"

#if (FAST_FLUSH_SUPPORT )
#define MEMORY_BUDGET_FLASH_DIR                   (12 * 256)
#define MEMORY_BUDGET_FLASH_CFG                   (15 * 256)
#else //(FAST_FLUSH_SUPPORT )
#define MEMORY_BUDGET_FLASH_DIR                   (0)
#define MEMORY_BUDGET_FLASH_CFG                   (0)
#endif //(FAST_FLUSH_SUPPORT )

#define DRAM_OFFSET_FLASH_DIR                   (DUMMY_ENGR2_LOAD_ADDRESS)
#define DRAM_OFFSET_FLASH_CFG                    (DRAM_OFFSET_FLASH_DIR            + MEMORY_BUDGET_FLASH_DIR)
#define DRAM_OFFSET_FLASH_LOG                   (DRAM_OFFSET_FLASH_CFG             + MEMORY_BUDGET_FLASH_CFG)

#define DRAM_FLASH_CFG_BASE              (DRAM_OFFSET_FLASH_CFG + ENGR2_LOAD_ADDRESS)
#define DRAM_FLASH_CFG_SIZE              (MEMORY_BUDGET_FLASH_CFG)
```

As you can see, it can get a little hairy. What I would like to do is resolve all of FILE_B's `#defines` to one evaluated level. Furthermore all conditionals would be processed and removed. (Assuming userware is TRUE),

```
#define MEMORY_BUDGET_FLASH_DIR                   (12 * 256)
#define MEMORY_BUDGET_FLASH_CFG                   (15 * 256)

#define DRAM_OFFSET_FLASH_DIR                   (0x92059020)
#define DRAM_OFFSET_FLASH_CFG                   (0x92059020            + (12 * 256))
#define DRAM_OFFSET_FLASH_LOG                   ((0x92059020            + (12 * 256))             + (15 * 256))

#define DRAM_FLASH_CFG_BASE              ((0x92059020            + (12 * 256)) + 0x6FF020)
#define DRAM_FLASH_CFG_SIZE              ((15 * 256))
```

If I can get to a point like this, then I can research the next step which would be to evaluate all of the right-hand-sides of the macros. So for example, MEMORY_BUDGET_FLASH_DIR would evaluate to 3,072.

The build process for these is long and cumbersome and involves thousands of files, so running gcc with the -E is not the best solution. In fact, it's probably one of the worse solutions since I believe that '-E' resolves all macro declarations, so I lose the initial definition. Also, the only files I actually need are File_A1, File_A2, and File_B, meaning that the other thousands of files are pointless in this scope.

I'm hoping to find a simple way to parse these statements.
I'm not too sure how to evaluate the expanded expressions, nor what kind of structure to store all this information in. I hope to write this in Perl since I have some small small experience with it, more so than Python.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Updated problem description to reflect real values. Clarified a little bit.

Comment: This isn't very clear.  What final output are you looking for?  Why can't you just wrap up these three headers into a simple C test harness, and then just call `gcc -E` on that?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Pointless constraints usually indicate homework! This is actually a somewhat involved little project.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The final output would be FILE_B with only the #defines where none of them are nested. As in, the defines themselves map to a single value, numerical or boolean, not other macros.

Comment: I hope you'e l;ooking for something simpler than a full-blown C preprocessor? If you want a solution to your problem then you must show the real data, or something sufficiently realistic. You don't show `File_A2` at all, and `File_B` has no `#include` statements. Is there something that defines `FALSE` and `TRUE` somewhere? If you fix those shortcomings I will look at it.

Comment: @Borodin I've updated the initial question description with real values. Hopefully this makes more sense. FALSE and TRUE are defined as 1 and 0 in another header file. I would manually add them before running my program so they would resolve to something.

Comment: @soplu: I still don't see the contents of `File_A2.h`. You need to tie this down much tighter for anyone to be able to implement anything.

Comment: @soplu: I see that you've edited your question, but I still read *"FILE_A2 is very similar"*. It doesn't look like you're in the habit of writing specifications. Please explain what this whole thing is *for*, as I can imagine a few ways that a real-life C preprocessor could fix all of this.

Comment: The key question is, if OP is going to process "thousands of files" of real C code, he is pretty likely to have every sort of preprocessor hell in his header files.  OP needs to strongly convince us that he needs much less that, to get a recommendation of anything less than "get a full preprocessor", or something that can parse processor files in a more sophisticated way than C.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but you might want to take a look at [Coan](http://coan2.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @Borodin You can just ignore File_A2 for now. All it has are macro definitions akin to File_A1. Currently they are separated into two+ files but I can easily merge them into one file.

Comment: Won't let me edit comments after 5 mins.
@Borodin Structure-wise File_A2 literally looks exactly like A1, just different names and values. If I want, I can merge them into a single file and call that File_A1.

My end goal is to have a list of #defines that resolve to a single value and not another macro.
#define x 2 (good)
#define x y (bad)

As Hasturkun suggested, Coan works pretty well but it doesn't resolve any preproc calculations containing '=='
Ex: #if ( (CPU_VERSION == CORTEXR4) || (CPU_VERSION == CORTEXR5) ) [where those are macros defined in File_A1] would not be evaluated by Coan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Perl, you can use [Marpa::R2](https://metacpan.org/release/Marpa-R2) — a general BNF parser.

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/rns/3b2f48477fc23d0ab0f7) parses the beginning of FILE_B from your qiestion to a tree (see output in the comment).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This look the most promising of the two options I've been presented with, thanks. I'll need to fiddle with it but I think this should work. And thank you for providing an example to get me started.